# Erro em eventos de teclado no Allegro

Tags: c, eventos, teclado

Estou fazendo um trabalho do meu curso usando Allegro, como indicado.

Preciso capturar os eventos de teclas soltas no teclado, para tal utilizei o seguinte:

```
al_wait_for_event(evento, &ev);
if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_UP){
   if (ev.keyboard.keycode==ALLEGRO_KEY_A || ev.keyboard.keycode==ALLEGRO_KEY_LEFT)
       cmd='a';
   else if (ev.keyboard.keycode==ALLEGRO_KEY_W || ev.keyboard.keycode==ALLEGRO_KEY_UP)
            cmd='w';
   else if (ev.keyboard.keycode==ALLEGRO_KEY_D || ev.keyboard.keycode==ALLEGRO_KEY_RIGHT)
            cmd='d';
   else if (ev.keyboard.keycode==ALLEGRO_KEY_S || ev.keyboard.keycode==ALLEGRO_KEY_DOWN)
            cmd='s';
}
```

Mas o evento retorna o valor da tecla 6 vezes ao invéz de apenas uma!

No código eu ainda havia incluído (anteriormente) essas clausulas:

```
al_install_keyboard();
[...]
al_register_event_source(evento, al_get_keyboard_event_source());
```

No que estou errando?

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: Qual o sistema operacional? Você está autorizado a usar um método alternativo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente o problema era um laço que circundava essa região de código ou a região que eu chamava `printf("%c", cmd);`. Não lembro direito, fazem 3 anos já.

Quem teve um problema similar: cuide seus laços (não entendi como ganhou tantos up's essa pergunta).

Answer (score 0):

Eu usei isso num joguinho que fiz, eu tinha que digitar o nome, ai fui concatenando a string com a tecla digitada:

```js
//FUNÇÃO PARA INSERIR NOMES
void LE_TECLADO() {
  int tam;

  readkey();
  if (strlen(nome) < 13){
    if(key[KEY_A])
      strcat(nome,"A");
    else if(key[KEY_B])
      strcat(nome,"B");
    else if(key[KEY_C])
      strcat(nome,"C");
    else if(key[KEY_D])
      strcat(nome,"D");
    else if(key[KEY_E])
      strcat(nome,"E");
    else if(key[KEY_F])
      strcat(nome,"F");
    else if(key[KEY_G])
      strcat(nome,"G");
    else if(key[KEY_H])
      strcat(nome,"H");
    else if(key[KEY_I])
      strcat(nome,"I");
    else if(key[KEY_J])
      strcat(nome,"J");
    else if(key[KEY_K])
      strcat(nome,"K");
    else if(key[KEY_L])
      strcat(nome,"L");
    else if(key[KEY_M])
      strcat(nome,"M");
    else if(key[KEY_N])
      strcat(nome,"N");
    else if(key[KEY_O])
      strcat(nome,"O");
    else if(key[KEY_P])
      strcat(nome,"P");
    else if(key[KEY_Q])
      strcat(nome,"Q");
    else if(key[KEY_R])
      strcat(nome,"R");
    else if(key[KEY_S])
      strcat(nome,"S");
    else if(key[KEY_T])
      strcat(nome,"T");
    else if(key[KEY_U])
      strcat(nome,"U");
    else if(key[KEY_V])
      strcat(nome,"V");
    else if(key[KEY_X])
      strcat(nome,"X");
    else if(key[KEY_Z])
      strcat(nome,"Z");
    else if(key[KEY_SPACE])
      strcat(nome," ");
    else if(key[KEY_0_PAD])
      strcat(nome,"0");
    else if(key[KEY_1_PAD])
      strcat(nome,"1");
    else if(key[KEY_2_PAD])
      strcat(nome,"2");
    else if(key[KEY_3_PAD])
      strcat(nome,"3");
    else if(key[KEY_4_PAD])
      strcat(nome,"4");
    else if(key[KEY_5_PAD])
      strcat(nome,"5");
    else if(key[KEY_6_PAD])
      strcat(nome,"6");
    else if(key[KEY_7_PAD])
      strcat(nome,"7");
    else if(key[KEY_8_PAD])
      strcat(nome,"8");
    else if(key[KEY_9_PAD])
      strcat(nome,"9");
    else if(key[KEY_0])
      strcat(nome,"0");
    else if(key[KEY_1])
      strcat(nome,"1");
    else if(key[KEY_2])
      strcat(nome,"2");
    else if(key[KEY_3])
      strcat(nome,"3");
    else if(key[KEY_4])
      strcat(nome,"4");
    else if(key[KEY_5])
      strcat(nome,"5");
    else if(key[KEY_6])
      strcat(nome,"6");
    else if(key[KEY_7])
      strcat(nome,"7");
    else if(key[KEY_8])
      strcat(nome,"8");
    else if(key[KEY_9])
      strcat(nome,"9");
  }
  if(key[KEY_BACKSPACE]) {
    tam = strlen(nome);
    if (tam > 0)
      nome[tam-1] = '\0';
  }

}
```